# How can I make fontspec avoid black italics with Charter in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, mac

OS X Mavericks includes a copy of the font Charter in `/Library/fonts/Charter.ttc`. This file provides six variants: roman, italic, black, bold, black italic, and bold italic.

As the following example shows, `\textit{text}` produces bold italics instead plain italics and `\textbf{text}` produces black text not bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charter}
\begin{document}
Here are some \textit{italics} that should not be so \textbf{bold}.
\end{document}
```

Here’s a screenshot (for non-Mac/Mavericks users) compiled with `xelatex`.

[image]

How do I persuade fontspec to pick the right parts of the six part font?

Comment: I've noticed the same with plain-xetex, so prolly not related to `fontspec`.

Comment: Just tested: `\font\it="Charter/I"` produces the bold italic, while `\font\it="Charter Italic"` produces the correct italic.

Comment: @morbusg, so is that a bug in xetex? It is at least surprising that the `/I` bold italic with this font.

Comment: I don't know, but I'd guess it relates to the file being a TrueType Collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `fontspec` package lets you specify explicitly the italic, bold, and bold italic fonts that should be used. This is useful for many obvious reasons, including when it's necessary to override incorrect font-related guesses that `fontspec` occasionally makes. Incorrect font guesses can happen under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, by the way.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont     = Charter Italic,
             BoldFont       = Charter Bold,
             BoldItalicFont = Charter Bold Italic,
             Ligatures = TeX] 
            {Charter}
\begin{document}
Here are some \textit{italics} that aren't \textbf{bold}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's up with the final 's' in the word 'italics'?

Comment: @Sverre - Yeah, I noticed that too. The *s* looks fine when I first produce the pdf file, but it gets mangled when I create the .png file to post as a screenshot. The *c* right before it doesn't look to good either in the png file, does it? It happens regardless of whether I compile the file under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I'm afraid I have no idea what's causing it. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

It depends to the Charter font you are using. I have the CharterITC and that one works very well:

[image]

Comment: So where does on get CharterITC? Otherwise, this might just as well be a comment...